# Опасно ли передавать третьим лицам свой SHA1 certificate fingerprint?

Tags: android, криптография

Чем может быть чревата передача третьим лицам своего дебажного SHA1 certificate fingerprint?

Comment: Передача *дебажного* сертификата, а тем более его хеша ничем не грозит. В случае релизного сертификата - передача сертификата позволит подписывать приложение от вашего имени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сертификат - это цифровой документ, который подтверждает ваше владение некоторым закрытым ключом. Его можно передавать другим людям хоть целиком, хоть по частям.

Отпечаток (fingerprint, thumbprint) сертификата - это хеш-функция от сертификата. Имея сертификат, любой может вычислить его хеш-функцию. А поскольку сертификат секретным не является, то и хеш-функция не секретна.

Вот свой закрытый ключ никому передавать нельзя.

---

Правда, тут есть некоторая терминологическая путаница из-за того что во многих хранилищах, включая файловые контейнеры и системное хранилище сертификатов windows, закрытые ключи хранятся вместе с сертификатами, из-за чего возникает ощущение что вы шифруете своим сертификатом, а не закрытым ключом.

Поэтому передавая сертификат кому-либо, всегда проверяйте что к этому сертификату не "прицеплен" закрытый ключ. Но к отпечатку сертификата закрытый ключ прицеплен быть не может, потому отпечатки можно передавать без каких бы то ни было проверок.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартно ничем, вы всегда его можете перегенерить и если надо, прописать новый отпечаток в консоли Google, удалив старый.

Конечно, если он прописан в каких-то платных API, это другая история, но это вы и так должны понимать.

Comment: То есть даже используя дебажный sha1 certificate fingerprint, можно развести меня на деньги?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, вы же сам сертификат не передаете. Но в теории SHA-1 признан не настолько надежным как предполагалось, возможно создать другой сертификат с такой же подписью. https://security.googleblog.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html

Comment: Не думаю. Это лишь отпечаток. Он присутствует в каждой вашей электронной подписи. Отпечаток годится только чтоб идентифицировать Вас.